# How to reset a parse tree

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, parse-tree

I created simple grammar for addition and substraction:

```
S : EXPRESSION ENDLINE      {printf("Result: %d\n",$1);}    
  ;

EXPRESSION  
    : NUMBER '+' NUMBER     {$$ = $1 + $3;}           
    | NUMBER '-' NUMBER         {$$ = $1 - $3;}      
    ;

NUMBER : NUM            {$$ = $1;}
       ;

%%
```

After reaching S terminal I would like to write new input after first result is printed. Unfortunately I received a syntax error after inserting a second formula. How can I achieve this? I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about resetting the parse tree; you need to expand the grammar to permit any number of lines containing expressions. Just expand the rule `S` to include recursive invocations, like this:

```
S : EXPRESSION ENDLINE      {printf("Result: %d\n",$1);}  
  | S EXPRESSION ENDLINE     {printf("Result: %d\n",$2);}
  ;
```

That might be a bit tacky, so you could add a new rule to the same effect:

```
S: RESULT
 | S RESULT
 ;

RESULT : EXPRESSION ENDLINE      {printf("Result: %d\n",$1);}
```

Comment: The first one won't work as expected, since it will print the results in reverse order and only when the input is complete. The second will work but will chew up parser stack needlessly. Always use left-recursion unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: @rici - Yes, you are right as usual. I edited to show left recursion, as I should have done in the first place!